# How to add custom cordova plugin in cordova app

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I used the plugman command to create a plugin in cordova

It created all the necessary files that is required. Then I added the android platform in the plugin.

Then I tried to add it in cordova app. I added it successfully but when I am trying to build the app it is giving following errors

[image]

What am I doing wrong. How I can add my custom plugin in cordova app.

Following is the code of .java file.

```
 package cordova-plugin-test-cordova-plugin;

 import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
 import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;

  import org.json.JSONArray;
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;
      /**
      * This class echoes a string called from JavaScript.
     */
   public class TestCordovaPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {

   @Override
   public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext     callbackContext) throws JSONException {
    if (action.equals("coolMethod")) {
        String message = args.getString(0);
        this.coolMethod(message, callbackContext);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private void coolMethod(String message, CallbackContext callbackContext) {
    if (message != null && message.length() > 0) {
        callbackContext.success(message);
    } else {
        callbackContext.error("Expected one non-empty string argument.");
    }
}
}
```

Here is my plugin.xml file :

```
        <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
        <plugin id="cordova-plugin-test-cordova-plugin" version="0.0.1"    xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <name>TestCordovaPlugin</name><js-module name="TestCordovaPlugin" src="www/TestCordovaPlugin.js">
<clobbers target="cordova.plugins.TestCordovaPlugin" /></js-module><platform name="android">
  <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml"><feature name="TestCordovaPlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="cordova-plugin-test-cordova-plugin.TestCordovaPlugin" />
  </feature></config-file><config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml"></config-file>
  <source-file src="src/android/TestCordovaPlugin.java" target-dir="src/cordova-plugin-test-cordova-plugin/TestCordovaPlugin" />
</platform>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: Please check sample here https://github.com/santoshshinde2012/CordovaPluginSampleTest

Comment: please check updated answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think from your reference you have missing in your java code. To create the custom Cordova plugin please look [here](http://santoshshinde2012.blogspot.in/2016/11/steps-to-create-cordova-plugin.html).

Please check your package name conventions in java file for more please check [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html).

Here the steps to create plugin and install in ionic application.

For the source and sample to check [here](https://github.com/santoshshinde2012/CordovaPluginSampleTest).

**Commands:**

1. plugman create --name Test --plugin_id cordova.plugin.test --plugin_version 0.0.1
2. plugman platform add --platform_name android
3. plugman platform add --platform_name ios
4. ionic start IonicCordovaPluginTestApp blank
5. (In App Dir) ionic plugin add [Your local test plugin path]

   > example :
   >   ionic plugin add /Users/Workspace/Test/CordovaPluginSampleTest/Test
6. ionic platform add android or ios

Update plugin.xml file in following way

```
      <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
      <plugin id="cordova.plugin.test.cordova.plugin" version="0.0.1"    xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
         <name>TestCordovaPlugin</name>
         <js-module name="TestCordovaPlugin" src="www/TestCordovaPlugin.js">
            <clobbers target="cordova.plugins.TestCordovaPlugin" />
         </js-module>
         <platform name="android">
            <config-file parent="/*" target="res/xml/config.xml">
               <feature name="TestCordovaPlugin">
                  <param name="android-package" value="cordova.plugin.test.cordova.plugin.TestCordovaPlugin" />
               </feature>
            </config-file>
            <config-file parent="/*" target="AndroidManifest.xml"></config-file>
            <source-file src="src/android/TestCordovaPlugin.java" target-dir="src/cordova/plugin/test/cordova/plugin/TestCordovaPlugin" />
         </platform>
      </plugin>
```

Hopes this will help you !!!

Comment: I followed same steps to create the plugin.

Comment: Please change your package name package cordova.plugin.test.cordova.plugin;

Comment: I changed the package name but still gettting same issue

Comment: Have you change your plugin.xml file ? Please check in my source code

Comment: I have added the code of plugin.xml file. Please have a look

Comment: change value="cordova-plugin-test-cordova-plugin.TestCordovaPlugin"  and  id="cordova-plugin-test-cordova-plugin"

Answer (score 2):

From the first line of error message, I think you have a syntax error in your java source code. You missed a semicolon in the first line of TestCordovaPlugin.java file.
As a simple guess, I think you miss the semicolon after the import statement.
The solution is, you can directly modify the java sourcein the Cordova project first, then sync the modification to the standalone plugin.

Comment: I have added the code of java file. Please have a look and update what I am missing exactly

Answer (score 0):

you can do one thing .you can create this plugin again with plugman but with different command i.e

```
plugman create --name AmILate --plugin_id cordovapluginamilate --plugin_version 0.0.1
```

and then follow same steps again.

I have used this correctly and it works
but when i make another function named myMethod in cordovapluginamilate with javascript and java class i got an error as [custom plugin error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSSks.png)

i am sharing my code for plugin on github  https://github.com/vishuhanda001/cordovaaddcustomplugin

i have commented coolMethod and instead have tried to use myMethod in javascript and java file but got above error while accessing it although if i uncomment coolMethod my plugin for coolmethod function only works.dont know whats happening
help please
?